# Delete all text after a specific occurrence in a string using bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a sequence:

> MALYYDHQIEAPDAAGSPSFISWHPVHPFLAVAYISTTSTGSVDIYLEQGECVPDTHVERPFRVASLCWHPTRLVLAVGWETGEVTVFNKQDKEQHTMPLTHTADITVLRWSPSGNCLLSGDRLGVLLLWRLDQRGRVQGTPLLKHEYGKHLTHCIFRLPPPGEDLVQLAKAAVSGDEKALDMFNWKKSSSGSLLKMGSHEGLLFFVSLMDGTVHYVDEKGKTTQVVSADSTIQMLFYMEKREALVVVTENLRLSLYTVPPEGKAEEVMKVKLSGKTGRRADIALIEGSLLVMAVGEAALRFWDIERGENYILSPDEKFGFEKGENMNCVCYCKVKGLLAAGTDRGRVAMWRKVPDFLGSPGAEGKDRWALQTPTELQGNITQIQWGSRKNLLAVNSVISVAILSERAMSSHFHQQVAAMQVSPSLLNVCFLSTGVAHSLRTDMHISGVFATKDAVAVWNGRQVAIFELSGAAIRSAGTFLCETPVLAMHEENVYTVESNRVQVRTWQGTVKQLLLFSETEGNPCFLDICGNFLVVGTDLAHFKSFDLSRREAKAHCSCRSLAELVPGVGGIASLRCSSSGSTISILPSKADNSPDSKICFYDVEMDTVTVFDFKTGQIDRRETLSFNEQETNKSHLFVDEGLKNYVPVNHFWDQSEPRLFVCEAVQETPRSQPQSANGQPQDGRAGPAADVLILSFFISEEHGFLLHESFPRPATSHSLLGMEVPYYYFTRKPEEADREDEVEPGCHHIPQMVSRRPLRDFVGLEDCDKATRDAMLHFSFFVTIGDMDEAFKSIKLIKSEAVWENMARMCVKTQRLDVAKVCLGNMGHARGARALREAEQEPELEARVAVLATQLGMLEDAEQLYRKCKRHDLLNKFYQAAGRWQEALQVAEHHDRVHLRSTYHRYAGHLEASADCSRALSYYEKSDTHRFEVPRMLSEDLPSLELYVNKMKDKTLWRWWAQYLESQGEMDAALHYYELARDHFSLVRIHCFQGNVQKAAQIANETGNLAASYHLARQYESQEEVGQAVHFYTRAQAFKNAIRLCKENGLDDQLMNLALLSSPEDMIEAARYYEEKGVQMDRAVMLYHKAGHFSKALELAFATQQFVALQLIAEDLDETSDPALLARCSDFFIEHSQYERAVELLLAARKYQEALQLCLGQNMSITEEMAEKMTVAKDSSDLPEESRRELLEQIADCCMRQGSYHLATKKYTQAGNKLKAMRALLKSGDTEKITFFASVSRQKEIYIMAANYLQSLDWRKEPEIMKNIIGFYTKGRALDLLAGFYDACAQVEIDEYQNYDKAHGALTEAYKCLAKAKAKSPLDQETRLAQLQSRMALVKRFIQARRTYTEDPKESIKQCELLLEEPDLDSTIRIGDVYGFLVEHYVRKEEYQTAYRFLEEMRRRLPLANMSYYVSPQAVDAVHRGLGLPLPRTVPEQVRHNSMEDARELDEEVVEEADDDP

I would like to replace index position 383 (Q) with nothing after it, so the desired outcome would be:

> MALYYDHQIEAPDAAGSPSFISWHPVHPFLAVAYISTTSTGSVDIYLEQGECVPDTHVERPFRVASLCWHPTRLVLAVGWETGEVTVFNKQDKEQHTMPLTHTADITVLRWSPSGNCLLSGDRLGVLLLWRLDQRGRVQGTPLLKHEYGKHLTHCIFRLPPPGEDLVQLAKAAVSGDEKALDMFNWKKSSSGSLLKMGSHEGLLFFVSLMDGTVHYVDEKGKTTQVVSADSTIQMLFYMEKREALVVVTENLRLSLYTVPPEGKAEEVMKVKLSGKTGRRADIALIEGSLLVMAVGEAALRFWDIERGENYILSPDEKFGFEKGENMNCVCYCKVKGLLAAGTDRGRVAMWRKVPDFLGSPGAEGKDRWALQTPTELQGNITQ

I have tried:

```
sed 's/"Q"//383' text.file
sed 's/Q//383' text.file
```

But that does not do anything.

In the long term I need to do with with a few other positions so a method that is flexible would be much appreciated.

All the best

Comment: A simple `substr` in `awk` would work here, like: `awk '{print substr($0,1,383)}' Input_file`.

Comment: `sed 's/Q//383' text.file` prompts `sed` to remove 383th occurence of `Q`, as there is only `69` `Q`s no action is taken

Comment: Please specify whether the file has any kind of line delimiter, or is just one long string of capital letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -zEi 's/(.{383}).*/\1/' file
```

Store the first 383 characters as a back reference and remove the rest.

N.B. the `-z` option slurps the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with cut:

```
cut -c 1-383 < text.file
```

Answer (score 3):

GNU awk:

```
gawk '{print gensub(/(.{383}).*/,"\\1","1")}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw it into the pool, `head` can be used to cut off after `n` lines, but also after `c` bytes:

```
$ head -c 383 text.file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you store your string in a bash variable you can use bash parameter expansion:

```sh
mystring=$(cat text.file)
echo "${mystring:0:383}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option: `dd`

```sh
dd if=txt.file bs=383 count=1 status=none
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` and `printf`:

```
 printf '%.383s\n' $(<text.file)
```